# For loops not functioning as I intended. (looping through txt files in python)

Tags: python, loops

So I am creating a program which needs to read each line in a .txt file called 'words' and add each line to a list. There is another .txt file that it reads from called 'more_words', which each line has to be added to a list aswell. The idea is that I need to compare one line at a time from 'words' with every line in 'more_words' to see how many lines are longer than the first line in 'words'. The problem that I have is that it only ever compares the first line in 'words' to every line in 'more_words'. I think the issue is to do with the loops because if 'words' contains 5 lines, then it will compare the first line against all the lines in 'more_words' 5 times, without proceeding on to the other lines in 'words' I will put some of my code because that will explain it better :)

```
for line in words:
        line=line.strip()
        line=line.split()
        for row in more_words:
                count=0
                sentence=row.split()
                if len(sentence) > len(line):
                        count=count+1
print(count)
```

I hope I have made it clear what I am trying to achieve, and as you can see I am a beginner when it comes to coding. All documents have been opened as readable but this code was not included. Thanks :)

Comment: If `more_words` is a file, you're exhausting that file with your `for row in more_words` loop in the first iteration of the outer loop, so nothing is left to use in subsequent iterations. Either rewind the file in every iteration of the outer koop or - preferably - read the contents of `more_words` into a list and then iterate over that list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trouble is that as you iterate through `more_words`, you eventually exhaust the file and an exhausted open file won't read again.

Try to convert it to a list instead:

```
more_words = list(more_words)
for line in words:
    # rest of the code elided.
```